# Correct approach to a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on a MySQL based SQL problem, the following is description and sample input:

[image]

And the following is sample output:

[image]

I've tried something like:

```
select ROUND( sum(i1.TIV_2012), 2 ) from INSURANE i1, INSURANCE i2, INSURANCE i3 where ( i1.PID!=i2.PID and i1.TIV_2011=i2.TIV_2011 ) and (i1.PID!=i3.PID and (i1.LAT!=i3.LAT or i1.LON!=i3.LON) )
```

But the system cannot accept this.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Pls share the exact error message with us! And there is a typo in the 1st table name.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `join`syntax.

Comment: There is no error, but the result is not correct, according to the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following SQL

```
SELECT SUM(i1.tiv_2012) total       
  FROM insurance i1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM insurance i2 
                    WHERE i1.lat = i2.lat 
                      AND i1.lon = i2.lon 
                      AND i1.pid <> i2.pid)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT i3.tiv_2011 
                 FROM insurance i3 
                WHERE i3.tiv_2011 = i1.tiv_2011 
                  AND i3.pid <> i1.pid);
```

Result

```
total
1711758.65
```